# On solving quadratic matrix equations

Tags: matrices, systems-of-equations, matrix-equations, nonlinear-system

I am in the 12th grade and I am not that good with algebra. Is there an easy way to solve quadratic matrix equations of the form $X^2 = A$ (or even $X^3 = A$) over $M_{nxn} (\mathbb C)$, rather than just calling

$$X = \begin{pmatrix}a&b&c\\m&n&p\\q&r&s\end{pmatrix}$$

then squaring it, and then solving a really unpleasant system of polynomial equations?

Comment: There's a lot to be said about taking the square root of a matrix.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root_of_a_matrix